# Setup & Deploy Project Localization with Custom Actions

Tags: c#, setup-project, custom-action, setup-deployment

Hopefully there's an easy answer for this...

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the basic Setup and Deployment Project template.  I have Setup and Deployment projects where the "Localization" property is set to different languages (English, French, Spanish, etc.).  These projects have a C# WinForm custom action that kicks off at install and allows users to set some of the configuration settings of the program it runs.

My question is this: *is there anyway to detect the value of the Localization property in the custom action app*?  For example, can it be passed through the CustomActionData property (I'm already doing this with some MSI properties)?  Or is there some way to programmatically determine it in the C# code of the custom action app?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, can it be passed through the CustomActionData property (I'm already doing this with some MSI properties)?

You might've answered your own question - I don't see why you couldn't do this.

Comment: I don't know how.  That's the question.  Is there maybe an MSI property or something that would have this information?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought you were using a WiX Installer project.